# Dual boot windows Bitlocker recovery solutions

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have dual booted my hp laptop with ubuntu and windows 11. Now upon boot it directs me to the grub loader where I have options of ubuntu and windows boot manager.
I can't seem to go into windows now because it goes into bitlock recovery everytime i boot and I dont have the bitlock recovery key.

Comment: Providing details on your Ubuntu product/release are usually helpful (*they give details of what software stack you're using, which includes the grub version here!*)

Comment: Grub will not boot encrypted Windows. But can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu?